# How to solve $10x=3^x+3$

Tags: logarithms

How to solve $10x=3^x+3$?
There should be two answers from the graph plotted, one should be 3, but how do I get the other one?

Comment: There is no algebraic method that solves this equation.

Comment: But why is there no algebraic method?

Comment: The solutions are $3$ and  $$\frac{3}{10}-\frac{W\left(-\tfrac{1}{10}3^{3/10}\log(3)\right)}{\log 3}$$ where $W$ is the Lambert function.

Comment: Asking why there is no algebraic method is both a naive and a good question. Most equations you can write down can't be solved by the kinds of manipulations you learn when you first learn algebra. Proving that some can and some can't is often difficult. The comment from @jjagmath uses the Lambert function. That was "invented" precisely to name the solutions to this kind of equation.